# SQL Select, Match one column but not another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables in an SQL Server 2008 R2 database, lets call them A and B. They look like this

```
A
--------------------
GUID     Primary Key
B_GUID   Foreign Key
Value    nvarchar(50)

B
--------------------
GUID     Primary Key
Value    nvarchar(50)
```

I want to select all rows from `A` where

- B_GUID in A matches GUID in `B`
- Value in A does not match `Value` in B

However, I can't figure out the SQL. Any help? :) Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM dbo.A
INNER JOIN dbo.B ON A.B_GUID = B.GUID
WHERE
    A.Value <> B.Value
```

The INNER JOIN matches the two tables together, on equality of those two columns, and the WHERE clause restricts it further to just two rows where that condition applies.

Comment: +1, awesome! I clearly have to improve my SQL skills :) Love this site though, working answer 2 minutes after posting question! Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

```
select 
  A.*
from
  A
join
  B on A.B_GUID = B.GUID and A.Value <> B.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.B_GUID = B.GUID  WHERE A.Value <> B.Value;
```

This is not tested but should work

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! If you post error messages, **please** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.

Comment: Why a LEFT JOIN?? The OP wants rows that are equal on that value - clear case for an INNER JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Note, there could be a possible drawback on above answers depending upon the situation: Say if you have records as below even though there is a matching record due to other none matching record you will find the output as mismatch.

```
TABLE 1     
GUID    B_GUID  VALUE
101 201 X
102 201 Y

TABLE2      
GUID    VALUE   
201 Y   
201 X
```

One alternate way to solve this is use EXCEPT clause query.